# Input[number] starting (not default) value

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm trying to accomplish something that is a bit out of the ordinary. I have a regular `<input type="number">` field with a designated min and max value where the user can input a year. When initially hitting the up or down arrow on the input field, the value starts at the `min` attribute's value. What I'm trying to accomplish is to get it to start at the `max` attribute's value.

Are there any straight-forward ways to accomplish this using either HTML or AngularJS? I could write some javascript to do it, but I would prefer to avoid that. Note that I don't want to default the field to that value on load, only when interacting with the control.

Note that the min and max values are determined at run-time from a table, so they can vary.

Comment: you could always just do a data-ng-init="whatEverModelThisInputIs = maxValue"  Or is there more things i am missing in your question, maybe a fiddle or code example?

Comment: @Mutmatt Doing that means that the textbox loads at that value. It needs to load blank.

Comment: Alright, sorry i miss-understood, your question is a might bit wordy.  I don't know of an "easy" way to do this, you should be able to with a directive but you may have to override some core browser functions with input[number]

Comment: I was afraid you'd say something like that. I'll leave it open in case anyone else has any suggestions, but I think that's probably what it's going to come down to.

Comment: You can achieve this only with a combination of JavaScript and HTML. You can write a simple listener for your input which listens to arrow keys. Then when an arrow is pressed, you can check for a value, if none exist enter a configured value. Unfortunately, I dont think there is a simple HTML way to do it even with extended angular markup